# What is condition that the sum of $n$ complex numbers eaquals their product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, products

Let $n\geq2$ and let $\{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$ be a set of complex numbers.

Is there a condition on the $z_i$'s such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n z_i=\prod_{i=1}^n z_i$$
is identically true?

For $n=2$ the condition that
$$a+b=ab$$
just becomes $b=\frac{a}{a-1}$, for $a-1\neq0$, but is there an inductive approach to solving the general problem?

My reason of investigating this is to learn about the class of linear operators $A$ with the property that $\det(A)=\mathrm{tr}(A)$, in which case the above condition is the condition on the eigenvalues.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Some work has been done when the $z_i\in \mathbb N$, see http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~anow/ps-dvi/si-krl-a.pdf

Comment: Maybe it helps to take the derivative wrt $z_i$ on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$r=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} z_j, \quad s=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} z_j$$

(Note the $n-1$ as the upper bounds rather than $n$.) Then your equation is equivalent to

$$r+z_n=sz_n$$

which is solved by

$$z_n=\begin{cases}
 \frac r{s-1}    & \text{if $s\ne 1$} \\[2ex]
 \text{anything} & \text{if $s=1, r=0$}
\end{cases}$$

(There is no solution if $s=1,r\ne 0$.) Therefore your desired condition is just on any one of the $z_k$'s, except for one special case where your equation cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Well since all the $z_i$'s are arbitrary, you will always be able to ensure that $s\neq1$ then it just becomes a condition on $z_{n-1}$ as well.